# Twilio not sending image to WhatsApp number

Tags: flask, twilio, twilio-api

I have a Flask app that receives a media file and sends it to another number. My program sends the request below to Twilio, but the recipient never receives the media. Instead, I get the errors "Error 11200 - Attempt to retrieve media failed," and "Error 14103 - Message body must be specified." As you can see, I provided the body in the request, but it still returns an error.

```
message = client.messages.create(
    body="test",
    from_='whatsapp:+19179949274',
    to=f'whatsapp:+16466737627',
    media_url=[media_url]
)
```

The URL of the media gets created and works, but the message containing the media doesn't get sent.

For context, here's the full program (I'm using Flask and ngrok):

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

# Twilio credentials
account_sid = 'redacted'
auth_token = 'redacted'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

@app.route("/whatsapp", methods=['POST'])
def whatsapp():
    media_msg = request.values.get('NumMedia')

    if int(media_msg) > 0:
        media_url = request.values.get('MediaUrl0')

        message = client.messages.create(
            body="test",
            from_='whatsapp:+19179949274',
            to=f'whatsapp:+16466737627',
            media_url=[media_url],
        )
        print("media message: ", message.sid)


    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that `media_url` is null or undefined? Can you try with a hard-coded value for `media_url`?

Comment: The URL is not null. I just discovered something weird: when I copied the media_url that I passed to the request (which starts with https://api.twilio.com...) and pasted it on the browser, it got redirected to another link (a longer one, that starts with https://mms.twiliocdn.com...). If I copy that link and hard code it in the request (media_url=https://mms.twiliocdn.com...), it works. So, if the URL passed is the one that starts with https://api.twilio.com it doesn't work, but if I hardcode the link that this link redirects to it works.
Any chance you could try replicating this issue?

Comment: I can try if you share the full URLs but this could be intended as you should pass the URL to the resource and not to a redirect. Did you copy that URL from a docs page? Maybe we need to update that page then.

Comment: I'm starting to think that it's an authentication issue that prevents Twilio from sending that URL (after all, when I open the URL that starts with api.twilio.com through a browser, it asks for my SSID and Auth Token).

Comment: Okay, I discovered what is causing the issue. Twilio made changes to its API and now requires HTTP authentication for stored media: https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/upcoming-security-changes-enforcing-http-authentication-for-media but I have no idea how to provide the necessary auth info to the link when sending the media to another number with client.messages.create(). Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I found this article that explains how to send the necessary auth info with curl, but I would like to do it with the Python library: https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/media-resource#retrieve-a-media-resource